# Laravel - How to resolve special Date issue from External API

Tags: laravel, guzzle

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I am having this model: Employee

Employee

```
 class Employee extends Model 
{ 
    protected $table = 'employees';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

   protected $fillable = [
          'staff_code',
          'first_name',
          'last_name',
       'date_of_birth',
      ];

}
```

That is,:

```
App\Employee

 CREATE TABLE `employees` (
     `id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
     `staff_code` varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
     `first_name` varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
     `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `date_of_birth` date NOT NULL

) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


Also I have an external api that comes in form of JSON get request.

https://api.employees.net/allemployees
```

I have viewed it with postman get request and I have something like this:

```
 {
    "ID": "1",
    "StaffCode": "STC001",
    "FirstName": "Japheth",
    "LastName": "Shalom",
    "DateOfBirth": "1992-07-11T00:00:00",
 },
 {
    "ID": "2",
    "StaffCode": "STC002",
   "FirstName": "Ahitophel",
   "last_name": "Nedum",
   "DateOfBirth": "1991-10-23T00:00:00",
},
{
    "ID": "3",
    "StaffCode": "STC003",
    "FirstName": "Joash",
    "FirstName": "Nathan",
    "DateOfBirth": "1979-09-22T00:00:00",
 },
```

and so on... this continues

Already I have created this function:

use App\Employee;

```
 public function index() 
 {  
     $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
     $res = $client->request('GET','https://api.employees.net/allemployees');
     $clientdatas = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);

     foreach($clientdatas as $clientdata)
     {
        $employee = Employee::firstOrNew(['id' => $clientdata['ID']]);
        $employee->staff_code = $clientdata['StaffCode'];
        $employee->first_name = $clientdata['FirstName'];
        $employee->last_name = $clientdata['LastName'];
        $employee->date_of_birth = $clientdata['DateOfBirth'];
        $employee->save();
     }
 }
```

The DateOfBirth that is coming from the external API is carrying a special character (T) along with it.  And the data type for date_of_birth in the database is date.

I want to save the data from the external API into the local database.

How do I format DateOfBirth from the API into date data type and remove T00:00:00 from it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just take what you need from that string:

```
$employee->date_of_birth = substr($clientdata['DateOfBirth'], 0,10);
```